# detect volume of other open websites or even apps with js (probably)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio, volume

Is this possible?
google desn't seem to have anything on this..

So that if a user plays a video or song on another website the volume in mine would automaticly decrease

Comment: No it's not, unless they are both your websites with some elaborate serverside scheme where they can communicate with each other.

Comment: shoud be.. come on chrome team!

Comment: No, it shouldn't. One window having awareness (or worse, influence) of what's going on in another window is dangerous.

Comment: just awareness and just on volume.. it would be cool

Comment: I actually agree knowing whether the system is already playing some kind of audio would be a harmless way for sites that play audio to be more polite. I don't see any attack vectors introduced by just knowing audio is playing somewhere else on the system.

Comment: It is most polite to mind your own business with regards to what a user is doing out-of-window. Unless a user explicitly allows you, of course.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.

If it were possible, it would have to be browser specific, and I don't see that happening.  Even though it seems harmless to know whether audio is playing in another application (or tab), that is a slippery slope that would inevitably lead developers to ask for more and more.  You are talking about poking a tiny hole in a very big firewall that is there for a very good reason.  The moment average users start to feel insecure about javascript in their browser being able to look outside the sandbox it lives in, we all go back to the dark ages of web development.

Comment: i see you'r point, but i believe it's the firewall that needs to adapt to user experience.

Comment: If this firewall is getting in your way, chances are you are trying to do something that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of other apps is almost entirely controlled by a variable assigned and owned by the program that assigned it. So to access it you would have to access another apps variables, straight through the danger zone...

I played around with this for a while trying to hack flash games (not maliciously, a skill I had to learn for work), and it would be almost impossible to determine what is controlling volume without actually interacting with the interface itself.

The main way this is done, is by looking at the value of a variable you want to change.

"i have 300 ammo, I want 1,000,000 ammo"

So you have to search for a memory address with a value of 300. You will find a bunch.

'Shoot some bullets'

By shooting some bullets, and searching for the new value, you can eventually find the memory address you wanted, however, this is a very arduous process, and you can quite easily crash your browser by modifying variables that should not be modified.

This is why it is likely impossible

Comment: that's a huge puzzle!! in that time i could do about 5 other features, too bad

Comment: Ya. One day there will be a wonderful utopian society where all shared variables and interfaces are entirely encapsulated by a greater platform. One day...

Comment: maybe it could be possible to make a browser extension to solve this

Comment: Ya, but it would have to interface on an OS level